# Throwing colour values into firebase results in json error

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull the red and green values into firebase.
If I run the programs (red and green) separately it works, but if I run the program with both of them together it doesn't work， the following Json error pops up

```
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type int32 is not JSON serializable
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from firebase import firebase
import time
import json



red_lower = np.array([-10, 100, 100])
red_upper = np.array([10, 255, 255])  # 这里是设置颜色
green_lower = np.array([35, 43, 46])
green_upper = np.array([77, 255, 255])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3, 320)
cap.set(4, 240)


def image_true_area(img):
    return np.count_nonzero(img)

out_number = -1
thresh = 200

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (3, 3), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)
    
    
    out_number = np.argmax([image_true_area(green_mask), image_true_area(red_mask), thresh])
    out_number = out_number if out_number != 2 else -1
    
    url="https://autocar-3885c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
    connect = firebase.FirebaseApplication(url,authentication=None)
    connect.put('/test/',data={'color':out_number} ,name="green")
    print('已傳送',out_number)
    
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(red_mask, green_mask)

    # 图像学膨胀腐蚀
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
    # 寻找轮廓并绘制轮廓
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # 寻找面积最大的轮廓并画出其最小外接圆
        cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (255, 0, 255), 2)
        # 找到物体的位置坐标,获得颜色物体的位置，可以来控制小车的转向
        # print(int(x), int(y))
    else:
        pass

    
    #cv2.putText(frame, str(out_number), (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    print(out_number)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: TypeError: Object of type int32 is not JSON serializable

Comment: When posting error-messages or stacktraces, please always post the __complete message__. Here (in Python) this includes files and line-numbers, to locate the error faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like *numpy* is returning the data in its own data-type `np.int32` whereas Firebase-API expects Python's primitive type `int`.

You can debug this, by printing the type using `type(data)` before putting to Firebase.
It also might help to convert it using `int(data)` before putting.

```py
    print('类型 (data type) ', type(out_number)) # return type from numpy might be int32
    connect.put('/test/',data={'color': int(out_number)} ,name="green")  # converting type to int
    print('已傳送',out_number)
```

See also:
[TypeError: Object of type 'int32' is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795525/typeerror-object-of-type-int32-is-not-json-serializable#49797251)
which also suggests a data-type conversion added to numpy-calls.